# openni2 color point cloud

Tags: ros, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow,

When I was using openni2_launch in groovy I had a topic `camera/depth/points_xyzrgba`. Or now I have only `camera/depth/points`. Is there any reason for that ? How can I recover the color of the Point Cloud now ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156541/openni2-color-point-cloud/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For openni2_launch, there are several arguments that need to be set in order to get color point clouds.  For the ASUS sensors, all you have to do is set `depth_registration:=true`, which will enable the hardware to create the color point clouds.  This should give you `/depth_registered/points` which you can display in color.  If you want to create color point clouds using software instead of hardware, then set `depth_registration` to false, and `rgb_processing`, `depth_processing`, and `depth_registered_processing` to true (should be set by default in openni2.launch).  This should give you `/depth/points` which is not color, and `/depth_registered/points` which is in color.  The problem I have discovered is that  `/depth_registered/points` does not display correctly when using software depth registration.  I do not get a color point cloud unless part of the camera is occluded and the point cloud is very small.

I would be curious to know if anyone else has had this problem or if it is repeatable for anyone else.

---

Originally posted by [agoins](https://answers.ros.org/users/20362/agoins/) with karma: 81 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1